# Laravel Passport - Get Client Secret by client id

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-passport

I have the **client_id** from oauth_clients and need to get the **secret**.
Not possible to make a normal Model query or DB query, since the **secret** property is protected.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can access the `client_id` and `client_secret` if you know the `oauth_clients` id:

```
/**
     * DefaultController constructor.
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->client = DB::table('oauth_clients')->where('id', 2)->first();
    }

    /**
     * @param Request $request
     * @return mixed
     */
    protected function authenticate(Request $request)
    {
        $request->request->add([
            'username' => $request->username,
            'password' => $request->password,
            'grant_type' => 'password',
            'client_id' => $this->client->id,
            'client_secret' => $this->client->secret,
            'scope' => '*'
        ]);

        $proxy = Request::create(
            'oauth/token',
            'POST'
        );

        return Route::dispatch($proxy);
    }
```

Comment: `$this->client->secret` is **not possible** because the secret is a protected property

Comment: I've pasted an actual code that works in my Laravel 5.5 project, try it, it should work.

Comment: The id is hardcoded there in the constructor, and at that point I dont have the id yet, since I'm using in some method down somewhere...

Comment: @Ardit as you can see in the constructor, I query from the database, so you could do this everywhere to cast the client object, then access the properties. What is your porpuse? Please, add further information to understand the problem and try to provide a better answer.

Comment: I used your code like that 
`$client = DB::table('oauth_clients')->where('id', $apiUser)->first();
$clientSecret = $client->secret;` and works great! Thanks alot

Comment: Glad to help. You can mark the question as answered.